# Using regular expression to extract number

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

How can I extract a numeric expression from a `string`, which may or may not have `underscore` or `hyphen`. For eg; like `2016-03` or `2016_03` or simply `201603`.

Sample strings:

```
s = 'Total revenue for 2016-03 is 3000 €'  # Output 2016-03
s = 'Total revenue for 2016_03 is 3000 €'  # Output 2016_03
s = 'Total revenue for 201603 is 3000 €'   # Output 201603
```

There are 6 numbers and in case we have either of `-` or `_`, then the total length is 7. There is no other `number` in the entire string.

I don't know how to use `if-else` in `regex`, so that in can include the logic of length 6 or 7. For simple strings like `201603`, I am able to do it -

```
import re
print(re.findall('\d{6}','Total revenue for 201603 is 3000 €'))
['201603']

print(re.findall('\d{6}','Total revenue for 2016-03 is 3000 €'))
[]
```

**Note:** I am looking for a solution where theoretically `_` or `-` could be anywhere in between the 6 length number. Like `123-456` or `123456` or `12345-6` and so on.

Comment: You can try [`(?<=^Total revenue for )(\d+[-_]?\d+)`](https://regex101.com/r/yKKuGd/1/)

Comment: `\d{6}` matches at least 6 digits in a row...

Comment: I suspect that in your case, whitespace boundaries will work, i.e. `r'(?<!\S)(?=\d+[_-]\d+)[\d_-]{6,7}(?!\S)'`. Probably, it will be simpler to split with whitespace and then test with `^(?=.{6,7}$)\d+[-_]\d+$`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It doesn't work for the case where there is no `-` or `_` `Total revenue for 201603 is 3000 €`

Comment: @CodeManiac I would like to specify the length as well because otherwise we may hit 3000 as well. There could be `_` or `-` or none like in `201603`

Comment: @cph_sto so there always at max  only one `- or _`  ? that will match only if it preceded  by `Total revenue for `, if your string structure is fixed then there won't be any case 3000 will match

Comment: @CodeManiac. It could be like `2016-03`,`2016_03`,`201603`,`032016`,`03_2016`,`03-2016`. At max one of `_` or `-` or none of these two.

Comment: @cph_sto the one i suggested will take care of these, if you have string in format, `Total revenue for  requried number is some random value`, if you're sure the required number is in standard format always you don't need length here

Comment: @CodeManiac That I can't ensure that a standard format will be maintained.

Comment: @cph_sto [`Demo`](https://regex101.com/r/yKKuGd/4/) look it takes care of all the values you said, but if the length of string can be anything else then `6 or 7` and you don't want to match then we need to add length logic too

Comment: Ah, yes, use `r'(?<!\S)(?=\d+(?:[_-]\d+)?(?!\S))[\d_-]{6,7}'` see https://regex101.com/r/Tv4mfI/1

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Sorry, doesn't work. Just tried it. :)

Comment: I missed the `?` again, sorry,  I edited the comment above and added the link to the regex demo.  I do not like this pattern since there are too many checks involved. Probably, the `(?!\S)` is still better at the end: `r'(?<!\S)(?=\d+(?:[_-]\d+)?)[\d_-]{6,7}(?!\S)'` or even doubled: `r'(?<!\S)(?=\d+(?:[_-]\d+)?(?!\S))[\d_-]{6,7}(?!\S)'`. Too much redundancy. I would combine a regex with some code.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew `(?!\S)` is a really good point, you should add it as an answer, `+1` waiting from my side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be two approaches: one is more readable with splitting the string first and then getting the first item that matches your required pattern, or  a less readable approach with a single regex.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/GX8Iud):

```
import re
s = 'Total revenue for 201603 is 3000 €'
rx = re.compile(r'^(?=\d+(?:[_-]\d+)?$)[\d_-]{6,7}$')
res = [x for x in s.split() if rx.search(x)]
if len(res):
    print(res[0])

# Pure regex approach:
rx = re.compile(r'(?<!\S)(?=\d+(?:[_-]\d+)?(?!\S))[\d_-]{6,7}(?!\S)')
res = rx.search(s)
if res:
    print(res.group())
```

So, in the first approach, the string is split with whitespaces, and a `^(?=\d+(?:[_-]\d+)?$)[\d_-]{6,7}$` pattern is applied to each item, and if there are any matches, the first one is returned. The pattern matches:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=\d+(?:[_-]\d+)?$)` - a positive lookahead that makes sure there is 1+ digits, then `_` or `-`, and then again 1+ digits up to the end of string,
- `[\d_-]{6,7}` - matches 6 or 7 digits, `-` or `_`
- `$` - end of string.

The second approach involves regex only and the `^` anchor is replced with `(?<!\S)` and `$` is replaced with `(?!\S)` that act as whitespace boundaries. `(?<!\S)` is a negative lookbehind that requires a whitespace or start of string right before the current position and the `(?!\S)` is a negative lookahead that requires a whitespace or end of string right after the current position.

Answer (score 1):

You can use positive lookbehind if you're sure your required value is always follow a standard pattern

```
(?<=^Total revenue for )\d+[-_]?\d+
```

- `(?<=^Total revenue for )` - Match must be preceded by `Total revenue for`, `^` start from start of string
- `\d+` - Match one or more digit
- `[-_]?` - Match `- or _` ( optional )

[`Regex Demo`](https://regex101.com/r/yKKuGd/2/)

---

Or you can extend the above regex in such manner if you're not sure that the required value format

```
(?<=^Total revenue for )(?=\d+[-_]?\d+)[\d_-]{6,7}(?!\S)
```

- `(?=\d+[-_]?\d+)` - To ensure `digit followed by - or _ optional followed by digit`
- `[\d_-]{6,7}` - To match `digit or - or _, 6 or 7 times`
- `(?!\S)` - Should not be followed by a non space character

[`Regex Demo`](https://regex101.com/r/yKKuGd/8/)

Comment: Though your code works, I am not used to the `demo` link you sent. What would be the first argument in `re.findall()` - `(?=\d+[-_]?\d+)[\d_-]{6,7}\b`??

Comment: @cph_sto yes you should add the pattern there, also if you go to link, there's a option on left side, code generator where you can see the sample code

Comment: Though, I accepted @Wiktor's answer. Thank you so much for your efforts and time. Very appreciated. I think I have learnt a lot here :)

Comment: @cph_sto always happy to help :) no problem even i would have selected his approach, because of smart use of `(?!\S)`

Answer (score 0):

This should do it fairly simply:

```
print(re.findall(r'\d{4}[-_]?\d{2}', 'Total revenue for 201603 is 3000 €'))
# ['201603']
```

Specifically, this is "Four digits, followed by either zero or one occurrences of either `'-'` or `'_'`, followed by two more digits". If there isn't a hyphen or underscore, the four-digits and two-digits just end up the same as asking for six-digits.

This *does* capture the hyphen or underscore if it's there, though, so one thing you can do is just filter it out:

```
nums = re.findall(r'\d{4}[-_]?\d{2}', 'Total revenue for 2016-03 is 3000 €')
# nums = ['2016-03']
nums = [num.replace('-', '').replace('_', '') for num in nums]
# nums = ['201603']
```

Note that this is the solution that least disturbs your original regex, and it'll search for this pattern of "four digits followed by maybe a separator and then two digits" anywhere in the string. If you want to restrict this to *just* the string you're trying to look for, ignoring similar ones, you may need to make the regex more specific. See also [the `re` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

Comment: I want a generic solution, where underscore could be like `03-2016` or `032016` or simply `032016`. Your answer assumes that underscore will be at 5th position. Theoretically speaking, the solution should capture cases like `123-456`.

Answer (score 0):

Your RegEx is following: 
starts with space, sequence of at least one digit(s) and ends with space.
It comes to this:

```
\s(\d*)\s
```

Check it here:
https://regex101.com/r/V4NzLj/1